# how to detect if device is pointing in a certain direction?

Tags: ios, swift3, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am building a game which requires that the user points their device downwards and then in front of them. How would I detect when the user points their device downwards or in front of them, using the device's gyro and accelerometer sensors?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CoreMotion with Accelerometer. Try this :

```
import Foundation
import CoreMotion

class CoreViewController: UIViewController {
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) 
    { deviceManager, error in
        print(deviceManager?.userAcceleration.z)
        print("Test") // no print
    }

    print(motionManager.isDeviceMotionActive) // print false
    }
}
```

Check the value that you get in the Z's acceleration. If it is positive it means your phone is face down. I didn't have a device so tested it on simulator. Check the positive or negative value of Z to confirm. 
Edit : Updated with Swift code.

Comment: Done Eric. Couldn't test it on a device though.